# how to set alarm at predefine time

Tags: android

```
@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

    Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

    calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
    calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    if(calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0){
        //Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
        calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }

    setAlarm(calSet);
}};

private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal){

    textAlarmPrompt.setText(
        "\n\n***\n"
        + "Alarm is set@ " + targetCal.getTime() + "\n"
        + "***\n");

    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    // alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
}
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether this time has passed already, else the alarm will never be fired.